# Bit.ly API not accepting "window.location", and logging an Illegal invocation error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bit.ly

I'm having a strange issue with an error while working with the bit.ly api that says:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

It seems to be an issue with the "long_url" variable, when I set it as a string, such as "http://www.google.com" it works, and returns the shortened url into the console, but if I set it to "window.location" it doesn't.

I can't see why it doesn't work (unless I'm being a bit thick)... any help will be much appreciated.

Code is below:

```
    function get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, func)
    {//use bit.ly api to get shortlink of item on share button hover
        $.getJSON(
            "http://api.bitly.com/v3/shorten?callback=?", 
            { 
                "format": "json",
                "apiKey": api_key,
                "login": login,
                "longUrl": long_url
            },
            function(response)
            {
                func(response.data.url);
            }
        );
    }

    //bit.ly details
    var login = "XXXXX";
    var api_key = "XXXXX";
    var long_url = window.location;

    get_short_url(long_url, login, api_key, function(short_url) {
        console.log(short_url);
    });
```

Comment: Hmm... As far as I know (As in, not that much) this should work. I haven't used JS in a long time, but try converting it to a String, as I think that window.location is a URL object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead...

```
var long_url = window.location.toString();
```

`window.location` is an object.

Comment: Beat me to it by only a few seconds, damn you! Ah well, this one is in answer form.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, all sorted out, will mark as correct as soon as the time limit allows me.

Comment: @NickHartley isn't that just typical on stack overflow! Always happening to me :p

Comment: @Archer It really DOES happen all the time... Ah well, no big deal. Not like YOU need more rep, though! :)